# How to make sure that all the tiles are rendering at all zoom levels using Open Map Tiles

Tags: openmaptiles

I'm setting up a map server and I have successfully uploaded the Planet
Vector and raster map tiles.But when I try to render the map in my web application some tiles are not rendering and Grey tiles are displayed on zooming.Is there anything I can do it make it render completely?

Comment: I am sing openlayers(XYZ) to render the same in web.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal code example?